# AWS Amplify not syncing up to Dynamodb

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I am working on a side project that involves AWS Amplify Datastore. Whenver I run the code below it says "Post added" signifying that the it ran successfully. However, when I look at the dynamodb instance created by this program there is no change. Why is it not updating?

```
import Foundation
import Amplify
import AmplifyPlugins


protocol Islands {
    func CreatePost()
}

extension Islands {
    func CreatePost() {
        let model = IslandPost(username: "fds", media: "fds", message: "fds", comments: "fs", likes: 1, time: 0.1)
        Amplify.DataStore.save(model) {
            switch $0 {
            case .success:
                print("Added post")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error adding post - \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
push=true
modelgen=true
profile=default
envName=amplify
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright it turns out that it wasn't an error with the code. AWS Amplify Datastore stores things locally, if you want it to connect to dynamodb you need to use the API features.

Comment: I experience the same issue. What kind of features you mean? Did you forget to do something like `amplify add api`?

Answer (score 0):

DataStore works local only by default. `amplify push` provisions the backend in the cloud and makes cloud sync available.

Comment: What would you recommend if `amplify push` worked perfectly, but the data are not syncing anyway?