# Items doesn't save correctly in dynamo db through the lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

In my react native application which has an AWS amplify backend I use a post confirmation lambda function to save the cognito users in my dynamo db data store. My post confirmation lambda function runs fine and I can see the newly created user in my dynamo db but I can't query that user inside my app and also I cannot see the user in admin UI interface. But after about several hours I can query that user and also see the user through admin UI. How to fix this ?

```
  /**
 * @type {import('@types/aws-lambda').APIGatewayProxyHandler}
 */

const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const ddb = new aws.DynamoDB();

const tableName = process.env.USERTABLE;

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  // insert code to be executed by your lambda trigger
  
  if(!event?.request?.userAttributes?.sub){
    console.log("no sub provided")
    return;
  }
  
  const now = new Date();
  const timestamp = now.getTime();

  const userItem = {

    __typename: { S: 'User' },
    _lastChangedAt: { N: timestamp.toString() },
    _version: { N: "1" },
    updatedAt: { S: now.toISOString() },
    createdAt: { S: now.toISOString() },
    id: { S: event.request.userAttributes.sub },
    Name: { S: event.request.userAttributes.name },
    Email: { S: event.request.userAttributes.email },
    Phonenumb: { S: event.request.userAttributes.phone_number },
    DeliveryAddress: { S: ''}
  }
  
  const params = {
    Item: userItem,
    TableName: tableName
  }

  try {
    await ddb.putItem(params).promise();
    console.log("Success");
 } catch (e) {
   console.log(e)
 }

  
  
};
```

this is my lambda function

This is how my query code look

```
const getUser = async () => {
 
    const userData = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
    const currentUserId = userData.attributes.sub
    
    await DataStore.query(User, currentUserId).then(setUser);
    console.log("getting user in home");
    
  };


 useEffect(() => {
     
  getUser();
    
  }, []);
```

Comment: what does the "query" code look like?

Comment: @petrch I have added my query code in the post

Comment: I think you are saying that your Lambda function runs at the correct time, writes an item to the User table, you can confirm that the item is there (using the DynamoDB console or awscli, for example), but after all that your Amplify client issues a query request for that same item and it fails. How does it fail (what is the response)?

Comment: @jarmod I inserted my query function inside a try-catch block but no error is shown but the user is not queried. The response that I'm getting from the await DataStore.query(User, currentUserId) function is as 'undefined'.

Comment: Don't use await and then at the same time. Better to use `const user = await DataStore.query(User, currentUserId);`

Comment: @jarmod Ok I changed my code like that and then I console logged the variable user then I get 'undefined' as the response. like this console.log(user)

Comment: According to the [query docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/data-access/q/platform/js/#query-data): "Queries are performed against the local store. When cloud synchronization is enabled, the local store is updated in the background by the DataStore Sync Engine." Do you have sync enabled?

Comment: @jarmod I'm not exactly sure whether I have enabled the sync I will check it. And when I create a user manually through amplify cli and then I can query that user but the users that are created by the lambda function cannot be queried. Can this be because the lambda function doesn't properly save the users in dynamo db table ?

Comment: The Lambda function succeeds or it doesn't. You can verify which by reviewing the logs and by using a third client (e.g. DynamoDB console or the awscli) to verify that the Lambda function wrote the item correctly.

Comment: @jarmod Yeah I can see the 'Success' log in the CloudWatch of my lambda and even I can see the newly created user in dynamo DB table also. I don't know where the problem is

Comment: I would guess that either you have Amplify sync disabled, or the sync is failing to happen.

Comment: @jarmod How to check whether I have enabled sync ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62867405/aws-amplify-not-syncing-up-to-dynamodb